# Deploying A React-Redux Webpack Server

Tags: reactjs, deployment, react-native, webpack, redux

After messing around with React Redux I am ready to begin the backend processing with PHP and MySQL on my website at x10hosting. How would I deploy my app?

Im a little confused. I believe I can also deploy it to android and ios if I am not mistaken? So I would compile the files in the terminal using some command and then upload to my server?

From what I hear you would need to have java supported on the server but correct my on anything if I am wrong. Im still new to this. I have heard of services such as Heroku but I havent looked into it too much. Is this better than trying to host the app files on my own website?

Comment: I recommend you look into heroku or openshift if you're looking for app deployment tools. To deploy on android or ios, there's a bunch of ways to do it. You could take a look at phonegap for starters.

Comment: Okay ill take a look at those. My main focus as of right now is to get it up and running on my webhost. What steps need to be done to achieve this?

Comment: You're kind of asking a lot in this question: Backend, frontend, mobile apps. I'd take it one step at a time. If you're using a basic php host, then just build your front-end as a bundle and then ftp that up to your host. You could get started with create-react-app: https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app

Comment: Sorry for the horrible worded question. I was in a rush. So I currently have an app ready to be uploaded using the Redux-React boiler templates from https://github.com/buckyroberts/React-Redux-Boilerplate. My question is how do I FTP this to be server friendly? Right now it is setup using 'npm start' to start the web server pack for hot reloading.

Comment: You could ask buckyroberts. I don't see any build task. There's usually some sort of build task which will create a bundle for your app somewhere. Best of luck.

Comment: Oh that makes sense. Alright Ill ask him. If not, is there any barebones template that is similar which has one included? If no how would I make the build script?

Comment: As mentioned, you could try `create-react-app`, which is maintained by the react team.

Comment: I saw this medium article and thought of you. Hopefully this can help: https://medium.freecodecamp.com/how-your-startup-can-leverage-production-grade-infrastructure-for-less-than-200-month-15c3724038b4#.lhu5plh5c

Comment: Joao, the `create-react-app` and running the `npm run build` as you suggested works great; however, that freecodecamp article you just posted is a LIFE SAVER. I dont know how much to thank you truly, this just answered all my questions about prototyping and production deployment! Awesome!!

Comment: Yes there's some stuff in there I'll be taking away too. Glad to help! Good luck!